# How to remove emoji autocomplete suggestions?

Tags: macos, mac, emoji, auto-complete

I would prefer to not have emoji's suggested. Is it possible to remove emoji's from the autocomplete suggestions on macOS? If so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is untested but I did find this method for disabling emojis in the Messages app.

[image: ss1]

**NOTE:** In any applications where emojis are supported you should find a similar item under that app's Edit → Substitions menu. Simply uncheck emojis per app.

#### References

- [How to Stop Automatic Emoji Replacing Emoticons in Messages for Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2015/04/28/stop-emoji-replacing-emoticon-messages-mac/)